# how to allow only arabic,numeric and special chars in textbox using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery filter text boxes (Preventing user from inserting certain characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994904/jquery-filter-text-boxes-preventing-user-from-inserting-certain-characters)

I want to allow only arabic ,numeric and special characters to be typed in my web page. i want to apply this thing using jquery or javascript. How can i do? Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jquery validate plugin.  Build a rule that limits the characters to the one you want (alternately, there may be one already), apply it to a class, and apply that class to all of your input fields.  Note that this won't prevent people who intend you ill from submitting other things - jquery validate sits on top of the form, and it's possible to submit stuff underneath it with a bit of hackery - but it will make sure that everyone who's trying to do the right thing is guided to the proper path.